# Detect when app is opened from LocalNotification

Tags: codenameone

I want to detect when my app is opened through Local notification and read the notification's Id, similar to Push notification Type 3.

LocalNotification should open a specific form based on its id or any hidden value, but it doesn't have a listener to read it's title, id or body when clicked.

Below is my LocalNotification usage:

```
final LocalNotification ln = new LocalNotification();
ln.setAlertTitle("Booking request reminder:\n");
ln.setAlertBody(currentBooking.get("BookingDetails").toString());
ln.setAlertImage("/booking_image.jpg");
ln.setId(currentBooking.get("BookingId").toString());

Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(ln, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE);
```

Any idea or hack for me to achieve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main Class you can add this:

```
public class MyMainClass implements LocalNotificationCallback
```

And then, you can override the method:

```
@Override
public void localNotificationReceived(String notificationId) {
    //do some stuff
}
```

Here are some usefull link: [java doc](http://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/notifications/LocalNotificationCallback.html) and [CN1's blog post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html)

Comment: Thank you for the solution.